# Why are my tables being spread out?

Tags: tables, floats, page

My tables are being spread out across a page, and using `t` for placement wouldn't help. What should I do? I've tried `\raggedbottom`, which does not work.

MWE:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
Blah blah blah.
\FloatBarrier
\newpage %Here the pages with tables begins.
\begin{table}[b]
... Tabular Blah Blah ...
\end{table}
\begin{table}[b]
... Tabular Blah Blah ...
\end{table} % Lots of the tables
\FloatBarrier
\newpage %Following this page is something that's not tables.
Blah blah blah.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: By default a text page should have  no more that two top little floats and only one bottom float. With [b]+[b] you avoid the possibility place both in the same page.  With [t]+[t] it may work only with two small tables. Take your time to understand  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) how float a table or figure ,   and how force the defaults when needed.

Comment: +1 for the pointer from @Fran towards the excellent compendium answer.  I'm commenting only to stress that the 'aha!' here is the often-forgotten point that the float parameters in `\begin{table}` (and figure) _permit_ LaTeX to place the float top/bottom/here, but don't _force_ it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To guarantee that the two `tabular` environments are typeset closely together, just use a single `table` environment.

[image]

Note that a `table` float on a page all by itself will be centered vertically by default.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some blah blah blah.

\clearpage % force page break and flush the float stack

\begin{table}
\centering
... tabular bla bla ...
\caption{bla bla}

\vspace{2cm} % set the amount of vertical whitespace separation
... tabular ble ble ...
\caption{ble ble}
\end{table} 

\clearpage % force another page brea and flush the float stack

More blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```